# How to make http request to Google OAuth directly from server

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server, google-oauth, backend

I have some Google OAuth credentials and I use these credentials to allow users to sign up and make an account using Google.

If the user doesn't click on sign in with Google once they've made their account.

I want the client to make a request to my server to recognize that the user is using Google OAuth which I've done and I want the server to make a request to Google OAuth to verify the email and password passed in the body of the request.

I don't want the user to be redirected to a Google OAuth page I want it to be possible by just using the server and not using any Google pages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's nothing to reproduce. I'm just asking if there's a way to make a http request to Google OAuth which will verify a Gmail account's email and password.